# flutter: how to scroll listview inside listview using a button

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, future

i have nested Listview.Builder inside my FutureBuilder one is scroll horizontally and one in vertically what i want is when i click on a button i want to scroll my horizontal listview  i passed a ScrollController to horizontal listview but when i press the arrow all of horizontal listview scroll not of the index.
How Can i achieve that...

[image: My UI]

here i my code...

```
Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 10),
                    child: FutureBuilder<List<Catagory>>(
                      future: categoryList,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          List<Catagory> model = snapshot.data!;

                          return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: model.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                List<Product> product =
                                    model[index].products;
                                List<bool> scroll=List.generate(model.length, (index) => false);
                                return Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(width: width * 0.5,
                                          child: Text(model[index].name,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                                              maxLines: 1,
                                              softWrap: false,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.red,
                                                fontSize: 16,
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(width: 30),
                                        Expanded(
                                            child: Container(
                                          height: 1,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        )),
                                        SizedBox(width: 40),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                            child: Container(
                                                width: width,
                                                height: 140,
                                                child: ListView.builder(
                                                    controller: _controller ,
                                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                    itemCount: model[index].products.length,
                                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                                      return Container(
                                                        width: 80,
                                                        height: 130,
                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                                                        child: Column(
                                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                          children: [
                                                            Container(
                                                              width: 70,
                                                              height: 70,
                                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                  borderRadius:
                                                                      BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                                                  color: primaryColor),
                                                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                                                imageUrl: product[index].img,
                                                                placeholder: (context, url) => const Center(
                                                                    child: SizedBox(
                                                                        width: 25,
                                                                        height: 25,
                                                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
                                                                imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
                                                                        Container(
                                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                                                        image: imageProvider,
                                                                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                            const SizedBox(height: 3,),
                                                            Text(product[index].name,
                                                              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                                                              maxLines: 1,
                                                              softWrap: false,
                                                            ),
                                                            const SizedBox(height: 2,),
                                                            MyText(title: (product[index].salePrice != '') &&
                                                                      (double.parse(product[index].salePrice) <
                                                                          double.parse(product[index].regularPrice))
                                                                  ? product[index].salePrice
                                                                  : product[index].regularPrice,
                                                              textColor: Colors.black54,
                                                            ),
                                                            const SizedBox(height: 3,),
                                                            MyTextButton(
                                                                width: 55,
                                                                height: 24,
                                                                title: 'Añadir',
                                                                fontSize: 8,
                                                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                                                backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                                                                cornerRadius: 5,
                                                                onPress: () {
                                                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                                                                            ProductType(product: product[index])));
                                                                })
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                      );
                                                    }))),
                                        InkWell(
                                          onTap: () { 
                                            _animateToIndex(5);
                                            // here when i press this i want to make horizontal list of specific index to scroll
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            height: 140,
                                            width: 40,
                                            child: Icon(
                                                Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                                                color: Colors.grey),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              });
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                        }
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      },
                    )))
```

My Animation Code...

```
final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
final double _height = 100.0;
void _animateToIndex(int index) {
_controller.animateTo(
  index * _height,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
);
```

}

i'm new to flutter i research too much but i didn't found any solution i have to submit this project please help me as soon as possible thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried using `ScrollController`s for your `ListView` ?

Comment: yes! but when i click on the arrow button all horizontal list scrolls

Comment: i edited the question please check

Comment: You should refactor your `ListView.builder` to a `StatefulWidget` so they have different controllers and states.

Comment: but i`m getting data from the Api that are nested like list of categories  and inside categories there are list of products like you see in the picture

Comment: So what ? Pass the data from the API to your widget and you are good to go.

Comment: but my ListView.builder is already in a StatefulWidget not in a Stateless